# Bootstrap - How to make columns horizontal in lower resolutions and vertical when higher

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I have panels that I want to be be horizontal when the width of the page is small (mobile) and vertical when the width is wider (desktop). When the width is small, the panels can be scrolled horizontally. Something like this:

```
Small (mobile):

    ☐☐☐☐☐☐

Big (desktop):

    ☐
    ☐
    ☐
    ☐
    ☐
```

I would like to have to the panels to be a set size when the screen is smaller (w: 267 h:215) and bigger (w: 324 h: auto). I tried using the grid system. I had luck with the panels stacking but fitting all the panels in one container when the screen is smaller is more troublesome even with. I tried this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container panels">
  <div class="row">
    // col-xs-2 because 2 * 6 = 12
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    // five more of these
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panels {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // this makes the text within the panels go outside of the
  // panel if it's really long
}
```

Am I approaching this right?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually the other way around but you can achieve it by specifying the width in large view:

```
<div class="container panels">
  <div class="row">
    <div lass="col-xs-2 col-lg-12"></div>
    // five more of these
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the panels are still small

Answer (score 0):

setting the container's style to `overflow-x: hidden` and removing `white-space: nowrap" does the trick

also declaring the size of the panel in a class solves the size problem